# best practices to send files to mobile client application

Tags: java, web-services, rest, ftp, download

We are building a backend Java EE application for mobile, mainly all the services are being built using Jersey Restful web services.

Our mission now is to transfer some files/images/videos that currently exist on Sharepoint to the mobile, my question is mainly what are the best practices to achieve this, I have the following thoughts

1. Getting the files from sharepoint to our server then the mobile side can stream them through Restful web service
2. Getting the files and putting them under proxy server and sending the URLs to the mobile through Restful web service

I really feel that there are some other better ways, please direct me or send useful links

Comment: Option 2 looks better. Not sure that the question is then.